# Goldbach function for list of even numbers [4..n]

Tags: haskell, primes

Hello I am trying to make a function `goldbach :: Integer -> Bool` for interval `[4..n]` that should return `True` only if all elements in that interval is even and can be summed from two prim numbers. So far I have done this.

```
goldbach::Integer->Bool
goldbach n 
    |goldbach2 n == ??? = goldbach (n-2)
    |n==4 = True
    |otherwise = False

goldbach2 :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
goldbach2 a = head $
                 filter (\(x,y) -> isPrime x && isPrime y) $
                 map (\e -> (e, a - e)) [3,5..a `div` 2]
where
factors a = filter (isFactor a) [2..a-1]
isFactor a b = a `mod` b == 0
isPrime a = null $ factors a
```

Function `golbach2` result looks like this `goldbac2 28 = (5, 23)`. How should I chek in my 3rd line `goldbach2 n == ??? = goldbach (n-2)` if result of `goldbach2 n` is correct and gives me two prim numbers?

Comment: Your description must be wrong, for, the only qualifying intervals are [] and `[4..4]` since in all the others there is at least one odd number. Hence, a short version of what you describe would be `g = (<=4)`

Comment: I don't get it how can that be. If I would enter `n=8` I should have a list `[4,6,8]` and it should return True.

Comment: Yes, you actually don't construct the interval `[4..n]` in your code. In the description, what you really mean is `[4,6 .. n]`

Comment: So how should i change it so that it would be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want something like:

```
 | let (n1, n2) = goldbach2 n in n == n1 + n2   =  goldbach (n-2)
```

Comment: Yes I think that is something that I would need, but could you tell me how should I use it, I can't just simply replace my third line with yours or can I?

Comment: I think you can, although I haven't tested it. The let ... in clause is the condition, and the single "=" is the value for that condition. Oh, and I forgot the leading "|". I'll edit that in.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is I am getting an error, that goldbatch is getting to few arguments

Comment: Yeah never mind it just needed `n` after `goldbatch2`

Answer (score 0):

I would write this like

```
goldbachInterval n = all goldbach [4,6 .. n]
   where
       goldbach k = .... -- property of being a golbach number
```